# Intentionally delaying the loading in dynamic templates

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor dynamic template

```
{{#animate type="bounceInDown" delay="200"}}

           {{> Template.dynamic template=fetchTemplate }}

    {{/animate}}
```

and this is the helper

```
'fetchTemplate': function(){

      var myui = "Tab";

       return myui;
   }
```

I know i can use template level subscriptions  http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe  but i want to internationally delay loading my dynamic template and in the period of delay,i want to display loading.

I am doing this to be able to center my loading icons and i want to see the position of the icon(its development work really,not something for production).

What options are available for doing this kind of thing?.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution that i found to be working

The js

```
/*****************************************************************************/
/* AccountSettings: Event Handlers */
/*****************************************************************************/
Template.AccountSettings.events({
});

/*****************************************************************************/
/* AccountSettings: Helpers */
/*****************************************************************************/
Template.AccountSettings.helpers({
'fetchTemplate': function(){

      var myui = "Tab";

       return myui;
   },
   'tl': function () {
   var g = Session.get('shouldRender');

   return g;
  }
});

/*****************************************************************************/
/* AccountSettings: Lifecycle Hooks */
/*****************************************************************************/
Template.AccountSettings.onCreated(function () {
});

Template.AccountSettings.onRendered(function () {
  Session.set('shouldRender',false);

 setTimeout(function () {
  Session.set('shouldRender',true);
  }, 5000);
  var g = Session.get('shouldRender');
});

Template.AccountSettings.onDestroyed(function () {
});
```

and the html

```
{{#if tl}}
            {{#animate type="bounce"}}

           {{> Template.dynamic template=fetchTemplate }}

    {{/animate}}

  {{else}}
    <div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-cube-grid">
  <div class="sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube"></div>
</div>

  {{/if}}
```